# paintComponent() isn´t working after including BufferedImages with an ImageLoader

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource, paintcomponent

My `paintComponent()` method inside my `JPanel` isn´t working after loading BufferedImages. The update method is running properly every 20ms (`swing.timer`) but the window stays white without any shapes or colors (which were there before I included the images). If I just comment on the `BufferedImage` `testImage` (see code) the `paintComponent` method is running again and displays the screen of my game.

I wrote the `ImageLoader` class several times and tried different paths. Most of them led to an error message, but now the path is working properly and the BufferedImages can be loaded. But now the window remains just white.

`paintComponent()` isn´t running. `Update()` is running and the shapes change their positions. But you can´t see anything. **I tried** to use `System.out.println()` in `paintComponent()` but the console remains empty as well. No output at all.

I don´t know which part of my code caused the error, but here you can say the `ImageLoader` as well as the `paintComponent()` in the `JPanel` class (at least the meaningful code)

**ImageLoader:**

```java
public class ImageLoader {

    public static BufferedImage load(String path) {
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getResource(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**In my JPanel class:**

```java
private BufferedImage testImage = ImageLoader.load("/res/playerufo.png");

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    /* Draw here --> I am not drawing any images yet. Just some colored rectangles */
}
```

If I try to start the program there is just a white window. There is no error message in the console. If I try to output the BufferedImage there is an output. It´s not null. But if I do not load the Image and instead write

```java
private BufferedImage testImage = null;
```

the game starts and `paintComponent()` is doing it´s job.
But why does my paintComponent "have a problem" with an `BufferedImage != null`?

Comment: That it's a static method doing the loading is possibly causing the wrong class loader (the bootstrap class loader, intended only for core parts of the API) to be used.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I removed the `static` modifier of the `load()-method`, created an instance of the ImageLoader and tried to load the `BufferedImage` with the ImageLoader object. But the result is the same. There is still just a white window without any error logs in the console.